# Pattern for re not retriving any results

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to create a re pattern in python to extract this pattern of text.

contentId: '2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08'
contentId: 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922'

The length of the content ID is 36 characters long and has a mix of lowercase letters and numbers with dashes included at position 8,13,18,23,36.

Any help with this would be much appreciated as I just can't seem to get the results right now.

```
r1 = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]*{36}$',f.read())
print(r1)
```

Below is the file I'm trying to pull from

```
Object.defineProperty(e, '__esModule', { value: !0 }), e.default = void 0;
var t = r(d[0])(r(d[1])), n = r(d[0])(r(d[2])), o = r(d[0])(r(d[3])), c = r(d[0])(r(d[4])), l = r(d[0])(r(d[5])), u = function (t) {
        return [
            {
                contentId: '2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08',
                prettyId: 'super',
                style: { height: 0.5 * t }
            },
            {
                contentId: 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922',
                prettyId: 'zap',
                style: { height: t }
            }
        ];
    },
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your regex? `*{36}` after the bracket `]` that closes the character group causes an `error: multiple repeat`. Did you mean `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]{36}$'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a typo in the regex in your question? `*{36}` after the bracket `]` that closes the character group causes an `error: multiple repeat`. Did you mean `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]{36}$'`?

Fixing that, you get no results because `^` anchors the match to the start of the line, and `$` to the end of the line, so you'd only get results if this pattern was alone on a single line.

Removing these anchors,  we get *lots* of matches because it matches *any* string of those characters that is 36-long:

```
r1 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]{36}',t)
r1: ['var t = r(d[0])(r(d[1])), n = r(d[0]',
 ')(r(d[2])), o = r(d[0])(r(d[3])), c ',
 '= r(d[0])(r(d[4])), l = r(d[0])(r(d[',
 '2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08',
 '                style: { height: 0.5',
 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922',
 '                style: { height: t }']
```

To only match your ids, only look for alphanumeric characters or dashes.

```
r1 = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{36}',t)
r1: ['2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08',
 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922']
```

To make it even more specific, you could specify the positions of the dashes:

```
r1 = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}', t, re.IGNORECASE)

r1: ['2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08',
 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922']
```

Specifying the `re.IGNORECASE` flag removes the need to look for both upper- and lower-case characters.

---

Note:

1. You should read the file into a variable and use that variable if you're going to use its contents more than once, since `f.read()` won't give anything after the first `.read()` unless you `f.seek(0)`
2. To avoid creating a new file on disk with those contents, I just defined

```
t = """Object.defineProperty(e, '__esModule', { value: !0 }), e.default = void 0;
var t = r(d[0])(r(d[1])), n = r(d[0])(r(d[2])), o = r(d[0])(r(d[3])), c = r(d[0])(r(d[4])), l = r(d[0])(r(d[5])), u = function (t) {
        return [
            {
                contentId: '2301ae56-3b9c-4653-963b-2ad84d06ba08',
                prettyId: 'super',
                style: { height: 0.5 * t }
            },
            {
                contentId: 'a887526b-ff19-4409-91ff-e1679e418922',
                prettyId: 'zap',
                style: { height: t }
            }
        ];
    },"""
```

and used `t` in place of `f.read()` from your question.

Comment: Extremely helpful! The dash based Regex got me exactly what I was looking for, a follow up question is if I'm looking to get the prettyId field how should I try to accomplish this? My thought is it should be the word prettyId with a : and then a set of '' with a wild card in the quotes. But not 100% sure how to write this.

Comment: @SkylerMartin you're absolutely right! Depending on what is allowed in the quotes, you might want `.*`, or `[^']*`, or `[a-z0-9]*`, or maybe something else. Btw, you can try out regular expressions online at https://regex101.com/ ([example](https://regex101.com/r/NT2fIM/1)), and [here's](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a decent tutorial.

Comment: Pranav Gisangadi This is a fantastic tool, and it gets me so close with [prettyId: 'a-z0-9'] but the results are bringing back a bunch of other stuff, is there any way I can make this more specific?

Comment: I think I'm actually even closer here's what I have r2 = re.findall(r"\bprettyId: '.*'",text) this doesnt return any results though is there something i did wrong?

Comment: @SkylerMartin your works fine for me: I get  `["prettyId: 'super'", "prettyId: 'zap'"]`. Are you sure you aren't making the mistake I pointed out in note #1 in my answer?

Comment: I believe i'm taking note of #1 by loading the file into a var  with text= f.read()

Comment: I found the issue, I posted the converted code that de-compiles some of it and makes it more human readable I was reading the wrong file. Thanks so much for your help!!